# Ionic 2 ion-datetime with displayFormat ="MMMM" is not changing the model value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using `ion-datetime` for the month and year dropdown values. When I put `MMMM` in `displayFormat`, it doesn't change the model value. However, if I put the `YYYY` in `displayFormat`, it works perfectly fine. Following is my HTML code:

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label>Month</ion-label>
   <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMMM" [(ngModel)]="filter_data.month"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
   <ion-label>Year</ion-label>
   <ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY" [(ngModel)]="filter_data.year"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

What I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Datetime | Ionic API Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/),

> It's also important to note that neither the `displayFormat` or `pickerFormat` can set the datetime value's output, which is the value that is set by the component's `ngModel`. The format's are merely for displaying the value as text and the picker's interface, **but the datetime's value is always persisted as a valid ISO 8601 datetime string**.

So as provided in the ISO 8601 ([W3 docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)), only combination leading to following formats would be allowed here:

- Year:
    **`YYYY`** (eg 1997)
- Year and month:
    **`YYYY-MM`** (eg 1997-07)
- Complete date:
    **`YYYY-MM-DD`** (eg 1997-07-16)
- Complete date plus hours and minutes:
    **`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD`** (eg 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00)
- Complete date plus hours, minutes and seconds:
    **`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD`** (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)
- Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a
  second
    **`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD`** (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)

This explains the behaviour of it not working with just `MMMM`.

**EDIT**:

This means it will not be allowed to use `MMMM` and hence the error. When you try to select a value for an `ion-datetime`'s `ngModel` having `MMMM` format, it would give following warning in the console:

> `Error parsing date: "[object Object]". Please provide a valid ISO 8601 datetime format:` https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Here's an [example plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Sm5WBFMfu1LIE3uXaQfq?p=preview) illustrating this.

Comment: I am using MMMM and it is displaying the month in correct format. Issue is with ngModel , it is not binding the value of month

Comment: @ZohraGadiwala I know. But it won't work unless your format is a valid combination of ISO 8601 formats. See updated answer for more details

Comment: ok got it. So what should i do to get the changed value of month??

Comment: @ZohraGadiwala unless you find a workaround, best way right now is to pick a combination of date that is valid.. like YYYY MM

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
filter_data: any = {month:"",year:""}

 <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Month</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMMM" pickerFormat="MMMM" [(ngModel)]="filter_data.month" (ionChange)="filter_data.month = datePicker._text"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Year</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY" pickerFormat="YYYY" [(ngModel)]="filter_data.year"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
```