# How to set default value for Month in Ionic2 form

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic2-datetime

I am using Month and Year in my html as:

```
<ion-col col-6>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Month</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMMM" pickerFormat="MMMM" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="month" (ionChange)="monthchange($event)"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
</ion-col>
<ion-col col-6>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Year</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY" pickerFormat="YYYY" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="year"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
</ion-col>
```

This is my Form that I am building:

```
'year': ['2000', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
'month': ['8', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
```

I am trying to set default value for year and month but I am able to do it only for year and not for month. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you try to set the value in fulldate ? like  'year': [ new Date().toISOString(), Validators.compose([Validators.required])] .. and try to console out the result of the form . simply console.log(this.form.value)

Comment: this means that you need to get the full date but you are going to show just what you need for example month and year . separately .. so this mean that the result is 08/(could be or any for now)/2000

Comment: Yes I did same and for the above code also I am getting the value of month and year both in console.log(this.form.value). But unable to show month selected as year

Comment: Seems as it is not allowed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441302/ionic-2-ion-datetime-with-displayformat-mmmm-is-not-changing-the-model-value